# How to switch the entire site to https while keeping the Search Engine indexed pages working?

Tags: magento-1.9, https

```
Magento 1.9.1 
Porto theme
```

Apparently Google will start penalizing sites that are not completely run on https.

I have 2 questions:

1. How to make it so that my entire site runs on https?
2. How NOT to loose any of the links that are already indexed by Google? I read that Google sees the same URL with http and https as 2 completely different things

Also we seem to have a problem with  the

> "Create Permanent Redirect for old URL".

I have that checked but Google found 922 Site not found Crawl Errors

they come up with a

> "404 You might want to check that URL again or head over to our
>   homepage."

Page on my site when you go to that URL.

We did change the category structure recently and I re-indexed everything after that.

When I go to CATALOG - URL REWRITE Management - it shows 330684 records. (I checked this a few days earlier and it had a Total 322505 records found which means an increase of 8000+ records in 2 days - why is that? What does this mean? And what do I need to do with it?)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to your htaccess it will be seen as a valid 301

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

all this does is redirects http to https

Answer (score 0):

First set the insecure base url to `https://` Based on your setup this  is enough to redirect the users if they try to use `http://`.

Maybe to redirect on web server level is better, as it avoids requests going through php first.

Next Thing

if you want a secure solution, you should add your website on https://hstspreload.appspot.com/ But be careful with this as changing the certificate can cause big problems. Let your Host to care about this part.

Comment: mudit: Thank you for your help. How does one redirect on web server level?